# Enabling input fields with radio button in ionic2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am new to ionic 2 and I could not find a proper solution for this.I have two radio buttons in my signup form. I need to enable two in put fields based on the radio button that is clicked. If radio button one is clicked input field one should be enabled.

Radio buttons

```
<div radio-group formGroupName="church">
<label>Church</label>
<div>
  <label>CGT</label>
  <ion-radio value="cgt" ></ion-radio>
  <label>Other church</label>
  <ion-radio value="noncgt"></ion-radio>
</div>
</div>
<div>
```

Input fields

```
<div>
      <label>CGT member ID </label>
      <input formControlName="cgtMemberID" type="text" disabled="true">
      <small [hidden]="myForm.controls.cgtMemberID.valid || (myForm.controls.cgtMemberID.pristine && !submitted)">
    member ID required .
    </small>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Church Name </label>
      <input formControlName="churchName" type="text" disabled="true">
      <small [hidden]="myForm.controls.churchName.valid || (myForm.controls.churchName.pristine && !submitted)">
      Church name required .
      </small>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do the reverse logic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44909707/disabling-input-field-based-on-radio-button-in-angular-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this:

1- in html:

```
<div radio-group>
    <label>Church</label>
    <div>
        <label>CGT</label>
        <ion-radio value="cgt" (ionSelect)="radio_select('cgt')"></ion-radio>
        <label>Other church</label>
        <ion-radio value="noncgt" (ionSelect)="radio_select('noncgt')"></ion-radio>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <label>CGT member ID </label>
    <input type="text" [disabled]="cgt">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Church Name </label>
    <input type="text" [disabled]="cn">
</div>
```

2- and in .ts file:

```
cgt: boolean = true;
cn: boolean = true;
radio_select(value) {
  if (value == 'cgt') {
    this.cgt = false;
    this.cn = true;
  } else if (value == 'noncgt') {
    this.cgt = true;
    this.cn = false;
  }
}
```

you also can add your form logic.

Comment: Runtime Error
co.radio_select is not a function     I get this error

Comment: I rebuild the whole code and it works now.Thanks alot.