# How to disable Text Field when radio button clicked in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have below form

```
      <form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="registerUser(form)">
    <table class="table borderless">
        <tbody>

      <tr style="width: 100%">
        <td >
            <div class="form-group">
       <input type="radio" name="ffStatus" value="radio1" checked > radio1<br>
            </div>
      </td>


      <tr style="width: 100%">
        <td >
       <input type="radio" name="ffStatus" value="radio2"> radio2<br>
       </td>

      <td >
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="DESTINATION" name="destination" [disabled]="true" required pattern="[A-Z|a-z]{3}">    
           </div>
      </td>
      </tr>


    </table>
    <table style="float:right;">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button mat-button  class="btn btn-outline-success" (click) = "getProfile()" type="submit" >Submit</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button mat-button  class="btn btn-outline-success"  type="reset" (click)="clearValues()">Reset</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

I want to disable destination text field when radio when radio1 is clicked and want to populate some text into it and enable when radio 2 is clicked.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44909707/disabling-input-field-based-on-radio-button-in-angular-2?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @HasanFathi In this example value is hard coded. but I want to enable or disable based on state of radio button . How to get the selected state in a function

Comment: you can change exampleFlag value in radio button change event

Comment: @HasanFathi I tried , but field is not disabled..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205601/enable-when-checkbox-is-check-in-reactive-forms?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially what you really need is to implement a toggling function that changes a boolean type variable whenever the radio button is clicked. Then bind this variable to the disabled attribute of the input text box.

Here's the simplified example.

**template:**

```
<input type="radio" name="ffStatus" value="radio1" (click)="toggle()" checked /> radio1<br>
<input type="radio" name="ffStatus" value="radio2" (click)="toggle()" /> radio2<br>
<input type="text"  placeholder="DESTINATION" name="destination" [disabled]="textBoxDisabled" required pattern="[A-Z|a-z]{3}" />
```

**ts code:**

```
  textBoxDisabled = true;

  toggle(){
    this.textBoxDisabled = !this.textBoxDisabled;
  }
```

Here's the demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jgv9vb?embed=1

Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your time. This code fits for my requirement